# Multi driver error in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, ram, error

Hi I am writing a code for image processing that includes a Ram to/from which data will be written and read. However, I am getting 15 errors like the one below.

```
[DRC MDRV-1] Multiple Driver Nets: Net address_ram[10] has multiple drivers: 
address_ram_reg[10]/Q, and address_ram_reg[10]__0/Q.
```

I created this ram by using block ram generator in Vivado 2017.2. It is single port ram and initialized with some .coe file. My knowledge on rams is limited. What I know or what I strongly assume to be true is that when write_enable is 1, data will be written to the location described by the address_ram. Does not matter if write_enable is 1, data will be read from the location described by the address_ram. By the way, ram is always enabled.

Here what I have

I read in rising edge of the clock and write in falling edge of the clock in order to avoid some clashing.

```
Reading_from_Ram: process(clk) is
begin
if rising_edge(clk) then
if (pos_x < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) and (pos_y <PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) and 
(pos_x >= 0) and (pos_y >= 0) then
address_ram <= (conv_std_logic_vector((pos_x + 
pos_y*PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT),16));
end if;
end if;
end process;

Writing_to_Ram: process(clk) is
begin
if falling_edge(clk) then
if (pos_x < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) and (pos_y <PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) and 
(pos_x 
>= 0) and (pos_y >= 0) then
write_enable <= '1';
address_ram <= (conv_std_logic_vector((pos_x + 
pos_y*PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT),16));
end if;
write_enable <= '0';
end if;
end process;

U4: Block_Ram port map(addra => address_ram,
                       clka => clk,
                       dina => data_in_ram,
                       douta => data_out_ram,
                       wea => write_enable);
```

data_out_ram and data_in_ram are used in changing brigtness and contrast.

```
U5: Brightness_Contrast port map(clk_in => clk,
                                 operation => operation,
                                 pos_x => pos_x,
                                 pos_y => pos_y,
                                 data_in => data_out_ram,
                                 cursor_pos_x => cursor_pos_x,
                                 cursor_pos_y => cursor_pos_y,
                                 length => length,
                                 output_of_operation => data_in_ram,
                                 mode => mode);
```

This is all I can say. How can I get rid of these errors??

edit:

```
Reading_Writing_Ram: process(clk) is
begin
if rising_edge(clk) then
if (pos_x < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) and (pos_y <PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) and 
(pos_x >= 0) and (pos_y >= 0) then -- if within picture
address_ram <=(conv_std_logic_vector((pos_x + 
pos_y*PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT),16));
if ( pos_x > cursor_pos_x - 1) and (pos_x < cursor_pos_x + length) and ( 
pos_y > cursor_pos_y - 1) and (pos_y < cursor_pos_y + length) then --if 
within cursor
write_enable <= '1';
else
write_enable <= '0';
end if;
end if;
end if;
end process;
```

I rewrote it again(code above) and solved the problem.
Thanks everyone who helped

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong : you are driving the address from more than one process. (As they are both driving it with the same computed value at the same time, you got lucky;  simply comment one of them out)

Comment: Also check your write_enable. I think it will always be zero. (but your code indent format is obfuscating a good analysis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing address_ram from two separate processes.  Just put them in the same process and it should work fine.

As a general note, when you multiply assign a signal in a process, the last assignment in the process overrides all of the previous assignments.  In many cases this is used to set a default value for a signal that is changed later in the process.